# Share code between google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, refactoring

I have a script that I use and update frequently for +3 spreadsheets, and I find it annoying to update each scripts separately every time. Would there be any ways to share (import/require) code from one place for each of those scripts?

I cannot have all these spreadsheets in the same file since they concern different clients.

My code contains functions as such:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Export')
      .addItem('iOS', 'exportForIos')
      .addItem('Android', 'exportForAndroid')
      .addItem('JSON-iOS', 'exportJSONForIos')
      .addItem('JSON-Android', 'exportJSONForAndroid')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: You can publish an unlisted Add-on if you want to keep the code private.  The user would need to install the Add-on.  Updates to Add-ons are propagated automatically without the user of the Add-on doing anything.  The author obviously needs to publish a new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script actually allows to use a Script as a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) and share code between various scripts.

1. I created a [stand-alone script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)
2. Set it's project settings and API execution key on console.developer
3. Took it's project ID and added it as a library on each of my scripts
4. Copied the main functions that I needed in the menu using the identifier I set (in this case, Trad):

```

```
function onOpen() {
  Trad.onOpen();
}
function exportForIos() {
  Trad.exportForIos();
}
function exportForAndroid() {
  Trad.exportForAndroid();
}
function exportJSONForIos() {
  Trad.exportJSONForIos();
}
function exportJSONForAndroid() {
  Trad.exportJSONForAndroid();
}
function exportForAndroidToDrive() {
  Trad.exportForAndroidToDrive();
}
function prefixSelectedCellsWith(chars) {
  Trad.prefixSelectedCellsWith(chars);
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Host it yourself (externally) and refer to it, would that work?

example:

```
  <script src=" http://www.yourdomain.com/yourscripts/thescript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it would. Gotta check if I can get permission to host it. You don't see any problems arising from importing functions such as the one I edited into the question?

Comment: Can they be hosted in Google Drive and referenced this way?